# After edit by another person, are my edit reps subtracted?

Tags: support, reputation, edits

Lately I edited some questions to improve them and I got 2 reps per edit. Now 4 of them are gone.

When I edit a post I get 2 reps. When after that someone else edits the same post, **do I lose those reps I got?**

Comment: Did those questions get deleted?

Comment: I don't think so because in my reps it doesn't display `removed` at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, additional edits following yours will not lose you the rep you gained.

The likely cause is that the posts you edited got removed and this is usually reflected in your profile under the reputation tab. See the below image:

[image: Removed edit]

One possible reason that you do not see `removed` entries is that you may not have ticked the option to `show removed posts` on the bottom of the page:

[image: Show removed posts]

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply, actually that might be the case, I don't know ... Yeah that sounds like a good reason! Thanks!

Comment: Um ... I've just taken a look at it and it nowhere says `removed` ...

Comment: That has happened me also in a few cases where the post was removed shortly after my edit was approved.

Comment: Ahhh that sounds plausible! All right, thank you very much!

Comment: There is another possibility as to why you don't see `removed` entries. I've updated my answer.

Comment: All right! Thanks and yeah that's exactly it! How could I oversee this box? Thank you!